# Does sku attribute in app.config determines against which framework the application is running?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have multiple frameworks installed on my machine.I have .NET Framework 4.6.1 and .NET Framework 4.8

If i build my application say with .NET Framework 4.6.1 and want to run it against 4.8. How do i do it?

Will adding the following tags in the App.config file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup>         
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8"/> 
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

make sure that the application is run against 4.8? Even though 4.6.1 still exits on the machine. If so how do i determine that my application has run against 4.8?

Comment: I just open the csproj file with notepad and check.

Comment: .NET Framework is globally installed on Windows machines. You can only have one version installed. However, you can explicitly state what version you have developed and tested against, and any compatibility behaviours .NET Framework has in a given version will apply to make it behave as if it were the older version. To see what version is actually running, call an API at runtime that will return the version number and see what it reports.

Comment: But Windows doesn't stop me to install multiple .NET framework version

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run the app with another .net framework version, you can try the following two methods to modify your .net framework version.

**First**, Please right-click your project **Properties**->Choose .NET Framework 4.8-> rebuild the project.

[image]

**Second**, Please right-click your project **Open folder in file explorer**-> Open the .csproj file.

Try to change:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

to

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.8</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

After saving the .csproj file, visual studio will show a message box, please choose reload all, then you can change it successfully.

Comment: I don't want to recompile the application,rather run it against the latest version.

Comment: @subbaraoc, do you want to update your framework to 4.8 or just want to know if your is running in the .net framework 4.8?

Comment: I want to know if it is running using .NET framework 4.8 or not when sku attribute is specified

Comment: @subbaraoc, I have updated my answer to use c# code to get the current targetframework. Is that you wanted?

Comment: Thank you.I tried it but it still shows the version using which the application is compiled with. Please let me know if my question isn't clear. I have an application built using .NET framework say 4.6 and now i want to run that application using .NET framework 4.8 rather than 4.6, does sku attribute help in this case

Comment: @subbaraoc, now I understand your question. I have provided two methods with you to change .net framework. However, you said that you don't want to recompile the app. Then, how do you want to change .net framework?

Comment: Consider i have a system A where .NET framework 4.6 is installed, i have an application which is on compiled on system A, now i want to run(without recompiling as it is an enterprise application recompilation is not an option) that application on System B where only .NET framework 4.8 is installed. Now while running the application on system B what is that the .NET framework will use

Comment: @subbaraoc, as usual,  the .net framework version will use the version 4.8 in the system B. If you are unsure about it, you can use the code to get it.

Comment: The earlier code which you had given was giving the version with which the application has been compiled with. 

Just an addition to the above scenario it if the system B has both 4.6 and 4.8  and if the sku attribute has 4.8 which version will the application application use?

Comment: @subbaraoc, If so, the app will use 4.8.

Comment: Thank you very much. The reason i had a doubt was according to the documentation of sku attribute, it says the application will throw an error if version mentioned doesn't exist, but it wasn't mentioned that it would be running against the version mentioned in the sku attribute.Just wanted to confirm my understanding. Thanks for your time.